# How to setup external access to my Azure VM running Kibana on port 5601?

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, remote-access, kibana

I am currently running a Azure VM on which I have installed ElasticSearch, Kibana and Filebeat. The idea is to have a reporting/dashboarding capability for log files which are also stored on the same VM.

Installation of the VM and this part of the ELK stack has been successful. I have also configured the Azure connectivity so that the Kibana 5601 is accessible externally (or at least that's what I think ;)).
When running a Azure diagnostics it shows a green light for the connectivity to the VMs IP adrress and 5601 port. I also believe I have I have configured the Elastic and Kibana config files the right way:

- For both Elastic Search and Kibana I am running version 7.6.2.
- Elastic has not been changed from the standard and shows a local host address.
- Kibana shows the 5601 port and public IP address that was given by the Azure Portal.
- Within Azure I have 'connected' the puplic IP address to the private IP address of the network adapter. [Azure portal IP-Config Inbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuKrG.png) [Outbound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4He6.png)

When I try to access Kibana through a RDP session on the VM's Chrome browser, all is fine. Obviously I use the local I address and port within the RDP environment.
When I try to log in on on an external device using the public IP address and Kibana port 5601 there is no connection.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issues, which seems to be connectivity related?

Comment: Have you opened port 5601 in the Network Security group assigned to this VM?

Comment: I did indeed. And also checked connectivity through the diagnostics tool on the Azure portal. All green... Which makes me wonder if I am overlooking something simple as a config change on Kibana..

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit Kibana server config file, so to allow it to be accessed by remote machine, otherwise only the local machine will be able to access the webserver UI. In `config/kibana.yml`:

```
server.host: "0.0.0.0" (instead of "localhost")
```

Config documentation :
[image]